# REPLACE and SPLIT String in SQL and create Variables from Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a string like this in a database field:

```
"Anz Längsteiler":0;"Anz Querteiler":0;"BoxTyp":"M";"Führungslänge":500;"Gewicht":40;
```

In PowerShell I can do this:

```
$Hash = @{}
($BoxDS -replace '"','') -split ';' | foreach { 
       $Val = $_ -split ":" ; $Hash[$Val[0]] = $Val[1] 
}
```

to get an output like this for further use:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $hash

Name                           Value
----                           ----- 
BoxTyp                         M
Anz Längsteiler                0
Anz Querteiler                 0
Führungslänge                  500
Gewicht                        40
```

Now I want to get rid of my PowerShell Script and create an SQL function.

Is there any way I can create a variable with the Name (as you can see in PowerShell output name column) and the value saved in there?

I'm very new to SQL and I read about `REPLACE()` and `SPLIT()` but can't really get my head around it. especially when it comes to dynamically creating the variables.

I'm on MS SQL Server 2016

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih just edited in, MSSQL 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sql-server version is 2016, you can try to use [STRING_SPLITE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function with `CROSS APPLY`.

I would write a subquery with `STRING_SPLIT` to split the `;` to be a result set.

> Splits the character expression using specified separator.

then write another subquery query to split the `:` by `CROSS APPLY` base on the upper result set.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 1 THEN t2.value end) Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 2 THEN t2.value end) Value
FROM (
  SELECT value as val
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(Replace('"Anz Längsteiler":0;"Anz Querteiler":0;"BoxTyp":"M";"Führungslänge":500;"Gewicht":40;','"',''),';')
) t1 CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.val order by t1.val) rn
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(t1.val,':') 
) t2
where t1.val<>''
GROUP BY t1.val
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/32540/0)**:

```
|            Name | Value |
|-----------------|-------|
| Anz Längsteiler |     0 |
|  Anz Querteiler |     0 |
|          BoxTyp |     M |
|   Führungslänge |   500 |
|         Gewicht |    40 |
```

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. As I see your solution here, I know now that I need to learn a LOT to really do this in SQL. But this is a very good strating point for me.

Comment: just a little thing - it does not get rid of the `"`, at least when I run it in SQLFiddle

Comment: @SimonS I edit my answer, just add `Replace` in the first subquery, before use `STRING_SPLIT` function.